# c++ udp broadcast. Do I need a socket to read and another to send?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, broadcast

I have seen many examples where they use two sockets. One to send and one to receive. But apparently both can do it. The difference that I have seen is that one is binded and another not. Example: [http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~dadi/compnet/labs/lab3/udp-broadcast.html](http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/%7Edadi/compnet/labs/lab3/udp-broadcast.html)

Comment: That depends on your protocol. You can send and receive on the same socket.

Comment: Each program needs its own socket. So if you have one "server"-like program it has a bound socket, then "client"-line programs creates their own sockets to communicate with the "server" program. The sockets in each program are bidirectional and can be used to both send and receive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can !

However Just be cautioned that the next read or recv might read a different datagram. UDP datagrams are always discardable you can still flag your recv() with MsgPEEK or something like that

see this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070395/c-receive-send-same-socket/67070457#67070457) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726931/c-udp-send-and-receive-on-the-same-socket) may be better

if your lazy here is the code from the topic

```
 struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
    int s, i, blen, slen = sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (s == -1)
        die("socket");

    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(1234);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(192.168.1.1);

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*) &si_me, sizeof(si_me))==-1)
        die("bind");

    int blen = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, &slen);
    if (blen == -1)
       diep("recvfrom()");

    printf("Data: %.*s \nReceived from %s:%d\n\n", blen, buf, inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));

    //send answer back to the client
    if (sendto(s, buf, blen, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == -1)
        diep("sendto()");

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```